# Where is _functools.py located?

Tags: python, functools

I was looking at how the wrap decorator was implemented in functools.py and it used `partial()`, which I then wanted to see how that was implemented.  It was imported from _functools so I looked for _functools.py but couldn't find it.  I grepped the whole python directory, and then my entire C: drive but nothing came up.  Where is this file located? (Win7 x64)

Comment: It's implemented in C, not Python.

Comment: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2545bfe0d273/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c

Comment: In these cases, I usually use `inspect.getsource(some_object)`.  If it _has_ source (due to being implemented in python), `inspect` will give it to you, otherwise it'll fail.  Alternatively, you could just look at the module's `__file__` attribute (which is present only if the module is implemented in python)